What Package i should install Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core 2020.1.114 for .NET8
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces. Install/reference Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 4.5.0 directly to project BaseProject.Endpoints.WebUI to resolve this issue.
BaseProject.Endpoints.WebUI -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 8.0.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 8.0.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces (>= 4.5.0)
BaseProject.Endpoints.WebUI -> Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core 2020.1.114 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis 3.3.1 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces (= 3.3.1).  BaseProject.Endpoints.WebUI D:\Repository\KimiaBaseNET8\BaseProject\BaseProject.Endpoints.WebUI\BaseProject.Endpoints.WebUI.csproj 1
i install some package but don't solve this

You could check if there's an updated version of Telerik that is compatible with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces version 4.5.0 or higher. If available, update the package to the compatible version.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
